# size of the description of an arrow vs the arrow's length

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, draw

In the following diagram, the upper horizontal arrow (`\varphi_{j,j+1}\otimes\varphi_{j,j+1}-arrow`) is not long enough for the description / the name of the arrow is too large right now, and I don't know how to fix that without renaming this arrow.
What I have done so far: I modified the size in `[row sep=1.8em]`, and I tried `\tiny varphi_{j,j+1}\otimes\varphi_{j,j+1}`. Furthermore, I scaled the whole diagram with `adjustbox` but I don't want the diagram to be a lot larger than now.

Therefore, my question is: How to adjust (in an efficient way) the length of the upper arrow or the description so that it matches, such that the diagram looks better?

[image]

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools, calligra, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,scopes,snakes,cd}

\begin{document}
 \[ \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.8em]
    M_{k_j}\otimes M_{k_j} \arrow{r}{\varphi_{j,j+1}\otimes\varphi_{j,j+1}}
    \arrow{d}{\sigma_j} & M_{k_{j+1}}\otimes M_{k_{j+1}}\\
    M_{k_j}\otimes M_{k_j} \arrow{r}{\varphi_{j,\infty}\otimes\varphi_{j,\infty}} & U\otimes U 
   \end{tikzcd}
 \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Your example code is not working. Remove `\[` and add `\end{tikzcd}`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will follow your advice from now on. And I edited my question, thank you.

Comment: You could add `column sep=6em` to the `tikzcd` options to change the horizontal distance.

Comment: thank you dexteritas, it works! And now the diagram looks good!

Comment: @dexteritas, do you have a mind to make an answer or we can consider that question is solved by comments?

Comment: feel free to write an answer, dexteritas. And I'm sorry, I have to be more patient with myself before asking. My problem was not a big deal ( even though it tooks hours for my trying to solve it)

Comment: @Zarko done. :)

Comment: Avoid the `pdftex` option: it's not necessary and makes the document not portable.

Comment: @egreg ok, I will avoid that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `column sep=6em` to the `tikzcd` options to change the horizontal distance.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools, calligra, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,scopes,snakes,cd}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.8em, column sep=6em]
        M_{k_j}\otimes M_{k_j} \arrow{r}{\varphi_{j,j+1}\otimes\varphi_{j,j+1}}
        \arrow{d}{\sigma_j} & M_{k_{j+1}}\otimes M_{k_{j+1}}\\
        M_{k_j}\otimes M_{k_j} \arrow{r}{\varphi_{j,\infty}\otimes\varphi_{j,\infty}} & U\otimes U
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. As soon I'm able to upvote, I will upvote your answer!